# Entity Framework 6 Code First check optional relation

Tags: entity-framework-6

I am stuck.

I have two entities in EF6 CodeFirst, let's say:

```
class Child
{
    public virtual Parent AssignedParent { get; set; }
} 

class Container 
{
   public virtual ICollection<Child> Children { get; set; }
   public Child ActiveChild { get; set; }
   [NotMapped]
   public bool hasActiveChiled { get { return ?????; } }
}
```

The later is mapped like this:

```
this.HasOptional(t => t.ActiveChild)
            .WithOptionalDependent(t => t.AssignedParent)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

*The logic: a parent has many children, but at most one is the active one.*

The tables and relationships are generated as expected. It is working just great in almost all cases.

But I need to test sometimes if there is any ActiveChild set or not.
The probelm is that the poperty is null when I don't use .Include when querying indifferent if the underlying table column (auto generated as **ActiveChild_id**) has value or is null. I can not always ensure to have .Include for that property. You might notice, that ActiveChild is not virtual, thus should not be lazy loaded at all.

1) Is there any way to map the generated foreign key to a property? It won't work if I simply add it and I can't figure out an other configuration that yields what I expect. And .WithOptionalDependent has no .WithForeignKey

2) Is there any way to get to the underlying **ActiveChild_id** field value? That would help me the most.

Thank you